# How to convert text files to GPX file?

Tags: java, android, xml, gps, gpx

I have a text files with latitudes and longitudes for different points separated by commas as follows. I want to convert it into GPX file so that I can use this to send coordinates from this file to my emulator. How can do this through a java class? My text file is as follows. I made this file by manually marking points on this site - http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/click-lat-lng-list/#.T-G4i7XztX8

```
28.499433450096404,77.4095070362091
28.49990488581077,77.40830540657043
28.500376319419054,77.40717887878418
28.50084775092117,77.40605235099792
28.5013191803171,77.40492582321167
28.501790607606893,77.40379929542542
28.502196033391538,77.40259766578674
28.502601457618425,77.40136384963989
28.503138878029674,77.40005493164062
28.503676295703638,77.39874601364136
28.504213710640236,77.39743709564209
28.504751122839448,77.39612817764282
28.505288532301247,77.39481925964355
28.505825939025602,77.39357471466064
28.50636334301247,77.39233016967773
28.506929028462302,77.39105343818665
28.507664415012268,77.39000201225281
28.50853178743081,77.38902568817139
28.509370869179346,77.38827466964722
28.510209944253397,77.38752365112305
28.511049012652865,77.38677263259888
28.51188807437762,77.3860216140747
28.512727129427535,77.38527059555054
28.513566177802456,77.38433718681335
28.51440521950231,77.38340377807617
28.515244254526948,77.38239526748657
```

Answer (score 2):

**GPX Sample:**

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
    version="1.1"
    creator="YourCompanyName">

     <wpt lat="Your latitude" lon="Your longitude">

       <time>Your Time</time>

       <name>Your Location name.</name>

    </wpt>

</gpx>
```

The gpx(GPS eXchange Format) file ends with *.gpx* extension

All you have to do is just read the text file line by line and create the tags and save the file as .gpx

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like you've gone through a lot of effort to solve your problem yourself.

See the documentation for the [GPX format](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp). Then use Java's XML utilities to write the file from your data.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, solution using awk:
https://gist.github.com/PanJarda/9f6c6b49247a6132cc4c2ab70082302f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).